# Dynamic WHERE condition based on variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the follow line in SQL Server

```
((@data_inicial IS NULL OR @data_inicial = '') 
OR 
tbSO.dt_criacao >= CAST(@data_inicial AS DATE))
```

I need to use the field tbSO.dt_criacao depending one parameter that I receive @cod_status.

If @cod_status = 1 I have to use tbSO.dt_criacao 
If @cod_status = 2 I have to use tbSO.dt_abertura 
If @cod_status = 3 I have to use tbSO.dt_fechamento

Can you help me in this issue?

Best Regards

Milton Camara

Comment: "SQL statement" what a descriptive title m(

Comment: You have very less accept percentage.. could you please accept answers for your past questions...

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't a CASE statement like that below meet your needs? You may have the then statement set a variable.

```
CASE @cod_status 
 When 1 then tbSO.dt_criacao 
 When 2 Then tbSO.dt_abertura 
 When 3 Then tbSO.dt_fechamento 
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps

```
((@data_inicial IS NULL OR @data_inicial = '') 
OR 
(@cod_status = 1 and tbSO.dt_criacao >= CAST(@data_inicial AS DATE))
OR 
(@cod_status = 2 and tbSO.dt_abertura  >= CAST(@data_inicial AS DATE))
OR 
(@cod_status = 3 and tbSO.dt_fechamento >= CAST(@data_inicial AS DATE))
```

Regards

Answer (score 1):

CASE Statement is beast way to put condition in a Query . you can use Case statement compute any new columns which is depend on other columns or condition . Also you can use case statement in SUM , AVG , count etc function . you can also put case statement in where condition .

you can use following syntax ..

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE
1 = CASE 
        WHEN (
               (@data_inicial IS NULL OR @data_inicial = '') 
               OR 
               (
               CASE @cod_status 
                    When 1 then tbSO.dt_criacao 
                    When 2 Then tbSO.dt_abertura 
                    When 3 Then tbSO.dt_fechamento 
               END >= CAST(@data_inicial AS DATE)
               )
             ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 
    END
```